# How to execute a script in zsh and then become interactive?

Tags: shell, zsh, execute, interactive

I want to run a predetermined set of commands after the invocation of `zsh` (i.e. after .zshrc is executed) that returns the user to an interactive shell when complete.

Things like this comes to my mind:

```
urxvt -e 'zsh -c ". scriptname"'
```

but instead of exiting `zsh` and the terminal once the script finishes, I want an interactive shell at the end.  The idea is to simply save users from having to type ". scriptname" whenever they log in.

Application: Several users are using the same account (strange but true) and I want to help in adjusting user specific settings. Yes, I know that one could use different accounts for that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really what you were asking for, but should have the desired result. You use an environment variable to pass the name of the user-specific script to source to `.zshrc` (or other appropriate startup file).

```
urxvt -e 'USERSCRIPT=scriptname zsh'
```

Then in `.zshrc` for the actual user, include

```
. $USERSCRIPT
```

---

(All of this is not to say that there isn't an option to run a command then remain in interactive mode; I just can't find a way to do it, so I offer this workaround.)